# QUERY if word exists in one of two columns

Tags: google-sheets

`"SELECT G, H, I, J WHERE AM = ""ROMARIO"" OR AN = ""ROMARIO"" AND J = ""IN"" AND G = ""TERCEIRO"""`

I'm trying to query in google sheets the word `ROMARIO` in `AM` and `AN`, but if I use the above syntax the `IN` and `TERCEIRO` are ignored.

Is it possible to search for a word in multiple columns that matches other criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses

```
="SELECT G, H, I, J WHERE (AM = 'ROMARIO' OR AN = 'ROMARIO') AND J = 'IN' AND G = 'TERCEIRO'"
```